# Show that the ring homomorphism $\phi:R\to R/I$ defined by $\phi(r)=r+I$ is well-defined.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, ring-homomorphism

Could someone please verify whether my solution is okay? It seems kind of short and I am not sure if I should add more to it.

> Let $I$ be an ideal in a ring $R$. Show that the ring homomorphism $\phi:R\to R/I$ defined by $\phi(r)=r+I$ is well-defined.

Well-defined: Let $r,s\in R$. Then if $r=s$, $\phi(r)=r+I=s+I=\phi(s)$.

> Should I add more to this or is it valid?

Comment: I don't see what there is prove. It's a standard property of *any* function, that if $r=s$, then $f(r)=f(s)$ (and any property of $r$ is a property of $s$).

Comment: What should be verified to be well-defined are the ring operations on $R/I$. Once it's clear, there should be no problem with $\phi$ being a well-defined homomorphism.

Comment: @Berci Thank you for taking the time to reply. Do you mean operation preserving? Or check well-defined for operations since we are working with cosets?

Comment: That the operations themselves on the cosets are well defined. For that you have to use that $I$ is an ideal. Everything else should automatically follow.